# Correct way to get a Non Null Count join in Stored Proc

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I need to get a ordered list back from SQL database based on count of addons from another table. This works fine except for when there is a null value for the addonCount how do I default addonCount to 0 when there are no addons found?

The following is a basic idea of what I have right now:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Foo AS b
        LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT Foo.foo_id, COUNT(*) AS addonCount FROM Foo_Addons
             GROUP BY Foo_addons.foo_id)
        AS p ON B.foo_id = p.foo_id
        ORDER BY p.addonCount DESC
END
```

Thanks much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the coalesce function.  Your outer select statement can do something like this:

```
Select coalesce(p.addonCount, 0) as addonCount
```

If the value is null it will return 0, otherwise it will return the count.

Comment: addonCount is not actually part of the table it is dynamic

Comment: Im sorry but im not seeing it..I have to keep the select * because i need the full results just sorted by count.

Comment: Sorry, I read your query wrong.  sgeddes is correct.  Can't you just enumerate all of your fields rather than using select *?

Comment: You are correct I enumerated the needed fields and the results don't return the calculated field anymore which is just what I needed. Thanks much.